# Clear interface config using macro and range in cisco

Tags: cisco, switch

I want to write macro which than i will apply to interface range and clear to default interface configuration in that range. Is it possible?

Comment: What Cisco IOS version are you using?

Comment: Version 15.0(2)EX3

Comment: `default int range gi0/1 - 24`?